# How much memory will Spring Boot Parent consume if introduced in existing heavy Wildfly Server (or in general)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-management, wildfly

There are 10 Projects already running in EJB Schedulers or Camel Routers in wildfly Integration domain.

A small work comes where need to consume data from database and send data to other system.

I am planning to use Spring boot now onward for future projects. We already went into heap space issues earlier on server so increased heap a bit and now things are stable

Could anyone suggest that Spring Boot will eat up much much extra memory and can lead to heap space issues?

In Simpler terms, how much memory Spring Boot artifacts(at least Spring Boot Parent) consumes when a project deployed on Server?

Comment: That depends on the artifacts. Since we don't know your artifacts, we can't possibly know. Run your own tests to see how much memory your setup will need.

Comment: @Andreas: I mean what if i only include Parent. No other module. I have edited question and make it more focussed to parent dependency.